# How to match pound/hash sign # in VBA Like

Tags: vba, ms-word

in Word VBA `Debug.Print "31#1" Like "31#1"` returns me False but using any other sign (e.g. ,&%'...) in both strings gives me True. However I need to use # here. How can I escape # so that Like operator matches my string correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator):

> > To match the special characters left bracket ([), question mark (?), number sign (#), and asterisk (*), enclose them in brackets.

In your case:

```
Debug.Print "31#1" Like "31[#]1"
```

Comment: Thank you. Google didn't help me finding this documentation. I was struggling with secondary sources which omits # as a special character and propose ~ to escape special characters.